# jquery post object and perl cgi

Tags: jquery, perl, cgi

with jquery i trying to post standard object to perl cgi script

js var data:

```
{
 alias: ["a1","a2","a3"],
 ip: "127.0.0.1",
 name: "name",
 port: "80",
}
```

js jquery post:

```
`$.post('/vhosts.cgi',{action: 'save',data: data);`
```

perl:

```
my $q = CGI->new;
print Dumper($q->param('data'));
```

result in Dumper is empty; Dump of $q shows that param names are `data[ip],data[name]` etc,

Dumper($q):

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             '.parameters' => [
                                'action',
                                'data[name]',
                                'data[ip]',
                                'data[port]',
                                'data[alias][]'
                              ],
             'data[alias][]' => [
                                  'a1',
                                  'a2',
                                  'a3'
                                ],
             '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
             'data[ip]' => [
                             '127.0.0.1'
                           ],
             'data[port]' => [
                               '80'
                             ],
             'action' => [
                           'savevhost'
                         ],
             'data[name]' => [
                               'name'
                             ],
             '.fieldnames' => {},
             'escape' => 1
           }, 'CGI' );
```

How i can get `data` as object or hash in perl ?

Comment: Show the exact output of the `$q` object.

Comment: That output shows that the parameters are not in the `'data'` param, but rather in `param('data[name]')`, etc. You should probably try to find a module more suited for jquery.

Comment: that is my question, best i see now is to encapsulate data with json, but may be here is more easy way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to write own parser utility for `data[...]`-like structures and mess with unicode problems and so on, you better use JSON encoding/decoding:

Client side:

```
$.post('/vhosts.cgi',{action: 'save',data: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Server side:

```
use CGI;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $data = decode_json($q->param('data'));

print Dumper $data;
```

I don't think it's so much hard way.

Comment: i just made the same :) Just wondered about why perl-cgi  not like that

Comment: It's not CGI.pm, it's jQuery, whuch serializes JS objects in a specific way:

Go to the Chrome console, try `$.post("/foo", {data: { alias: ["a1","a2","a3"],  ip: "127.0.0.1",  name: "name",  port: "80", }});`

Then go to Network tab and see what actually was sent to the server.

Comment: but php gets this, so it is not jquery-only way to serialize data